# Export each object on scene to another file

Tags: python, export, blender, blender-2.50

I want to ask you, how can I export all objects to scene to seperate files in blender using python scripts ? I want to export it to fbx, to have something like this:
Object      File
Car         Car.fbx
Boat        Boat.fbx
etc..

Each object will be have his of file.
I'm tring to use 'export_fbx.py', I paste source to editor in blender, and write something below pasted code like:

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    save(bpy.ops.mesh,ob,'C:\\images\\'+ ob.name + '.fbx')
```

But this doesn't work :/
I need something like this, beacouse I have 45 objects in scene, and I have to export each other to fbx, to import it in XNA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_61_0/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx

loop over all objects in the scene selecting each individually and calling bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx with the use_selection parameter set